# I want to create a hidden form that manipulates some windows processes

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I want to create a hidden app that is always on ,I want this app to detect if a process with a specific text is open to open another app and place it always on top.
For example:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Hide();
            if (Process.text == "DFT Report Generator")//if the process text is this text for example
              {
                Process.Start("someapp.exe");//start someapp
                someapp.TopMost = true; //set the someapp to be always on top
              }    
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

[image: This is the app that must be detected after its text name]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You mean you want to monitor window titles and look for specific ones?

Comment: I mean that ,I can't seem to find this app "DFT Report Generator" in processes even tho I am using process explorer to see all processes,so I was thinking about hooking after it's name.When a person starts this app("DFT Report Generator") I want my app to detect it and open another app,and place this new opened app over it and set it to something like TopMost=true;

Comment: OK but that code shows nothing iterating through running processes.. have a google on running through other process windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use right tool for the job.
Use windows service project template for creating windows service.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a window less forms application that runs in background. The rough idea is to create a Windows Forms application and disable the visual properties.

**Program.cs**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        //Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        //Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

**Form.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();
    }


    #region Silent mode

    private static Form1 _instance;

    /// <summary>
    /// Prevent window getting visible
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
    {
        // Prevent window getting visible            
        CreateHandle();
        _instance = this;

        //do not show the window
        value = false;

        base.SetVisibleCore(value);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

2. Have a timer trigger at specific interval, browse the running processes and achieve what you want to do.

   ```
   Timer _timer;

   public Form1()
   {
       //InitializeComponent();
       _timer = new Timer();
       _timer.Interval = 1000; //ms
       _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
   }

   private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
   {
       foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
       {
           //compare and perform tasks
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is method what I use. processName is name of process you trying to find and newPrecessPath is path to process you wont to run
If you wont to hide your main from just use this.Hide()
You can use this method in timer to trying find running process every x second.

```
private void LookProcess(string processName, string newProcessPath)
        {
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (process.ProcessName == processName)
                {
                    ProcessStartInfo prcinf = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    prcinf.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
                    prcinf.FileName = newProcessPath;

                    Process.Start(prcinfprc);
                }
            }
        }
```